# Leaking Garden Tub

Tags: leak, bathtub, valve

I have a leaking Garden Tub on the 2nd Floor. I have cut a hole in the sheet rock underneath and I have water dripping down both the hot and cold pipes leading up to the tub. I have not seen any leaking around the fixtures. Would the water valve Cartridges cause this or would the rough in valves need to be replaced? The fixtures are located on the tub so hoping of not having to ripping everything out. Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: It's all speculation at this point.  You need to identify where the leak is coming from and then figure out how best to fix it.

Comment: Over tightened supply lines, forgetting to pull valves on sweated body’s are 2 places I have seen leaks in the past , if it only leaks wile the water is running I have seen some spigots that had plastic pipe that was cracked. One trick is to take a hand full of flour (for cooking) and dust the area, the wet spots show quickly when the water drips are hard to see in this case.

Comment: There is also a possibility that it is condensation on the surface of the pipes. Is the leak steady?

Comment: It seems to be when the valve is open, their isn't any leaking where the handle is only running down the pipe of the hot water, where i have cut into the ceiling the water is a slow and steady drip. I hate to ask but if its the something i can replace from the top I can handle it but if Its the rough in valve its above my pay grade. Thanks again

Comment: Pictures never hurt either...

Comment: It appears you've created a second account. Please [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.